# Unset array Items matching a pattern

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following Array :

```
Array
{
    [0]=>"www.abc.com/directory/test";
    [1]=>"www.abc.com/test";
    [2]=>"www.abc.com/directory/test";
    [3]=>"www.abc.com/test";
}
```

I only want the items that have something in middle in URL like `/directory/` and unset the items that do not have that.

Output should be like:

```
Array
{
   [0]=>"www.abc.com/directory/test";                           
   [1]=>"www.abc.com/directory/test";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and into which problem did you run with it? Is there something special about the strings? They don't look like valid URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example without closures. Sometimes you just need to understand the basics first, before you can move on to the neater stuff.

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
  if ( strpos( $value, '/directory/') ) {
     $newArray[] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) this:

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($el) {
    $parts = parse_url($el);
    return substr_count($parts['path'], '/') > 1;
});
```

If you have something inside `path` will allways contain at least 2 slashes.

So for input data

```
$data = Array(
    "http://www.abc.com/directory/test",
    "www.abc.com/test",
    "www.abc.com/directory/test",
    "www.abc.com/test/123"
);
```

you output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.abc.com/directory/test
    [2] => www.abc.com/directory/test
    [3] => www.abc.com/test/123
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of approaches:

```
$urls = array(
    'www.abc.com/directory/test',
    'www.abc.com/test',
    'www.abc.com/foo/directory/test',
    'www.abc.com/foo/test',
);

$matches = array();

// if you want /directory/ to appear anywhere:
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if (strpos($url, '/directory/')) {
        $matches[] = $url;
    }   
}

var_dump($matches);

$matches = array();

// if you want /directory/ to be the first path:
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    // make the strings valid URLs
    if (0 !== strpos($url, 'http://')) {
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }   

    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (isset($parts['path']) && substr($parts['path'], 0, 11) === '/directory/') {
        $matches[] = $url;
    }   
}

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
      $array = Array("www.abc.com/directory/test",
                "www.abc.com/test",
                "www.abc.com/directory/test",
                "www.abc.com/test",
              );

var_dump($array);

array_walk($array, function($val,$key) use(&$array){ 
     if (!strpos($val, 'directory')) { 
         unset($array[$key]);
     }
 });

var_dump($array);
```

php >= 5.3.0